# ValueError, Datetime does not match format

Tags: python, csv

I got a CSV I want to work with imported. Trying to define the format of the time I get an ValueError.

This is how my data is formatted inside the CSV:
1979-01-01 06:00:00 +0000 UTC

This is how I use datetime:

```
headers = ['dt', 'dt_iso', 'timezone', 'city_name', 'lat', 'lon', 'temp', 'visibility', 'dew_point', 'feels_like',
           'temp_min', 'temp_max', 'pressure', 'sea_level', 'grnd_level', 'humidity', 'wind_speed', 'wind_deg',
           'wind_gust', 'rain_1h', 'rain_3h', 'snow_1h', 'snow_3h', 'clouds_all', 'weather_id', 'weather_main',
           'weather_description', 'weather_icon']


df = pd.read_csv('/Users/yourname/Desktop/Historical.csv', names=headers)
df['dt_iso'] = df['dt_iso'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z %Z'))
x = df['dt_iso']
y = df['temp']
```

This is the error I get:
ValueError: time data 'dt_iso' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z %Z'

Appreciate any help and advice!

Comment: it works fine for me. My code is 
`df = pd.DataFrame({'dt_iso': ['1979-01-01 06:00:00 +0000 UTC']})

df['dt_iso'] = df['dt_iso'].map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z %Z'))
`. Are you sure you are importing correctly the csv?

Comment: @chattershuts this is how I did it, updated it in the original post. I copied the headers from the csv.

Comment: The error was that there was already a header in the textfile. So I kind of doubled it with the headers statement ! Thanks for your help! Now my code works.